# Using Python: how to get table names from sql query and add a word before the table schema where schemas are present

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have a json file that I am using as a dictionary in Python. The json file is very large. I am trying to write a python code to update each "query" by adding a "source." before the table schema. then use the updated dictionary for other programming purposes.

The SQL scripts could have joins, cartesian joins, subqueries, etc.

Expected output:

```
 "query": "SELECT a.column1, b.column2
 FROM source.abcd.hist a, source.efgh.present b
 WHERE (select column3, column4 from UPS where a.id = b.id )"

 "query": "SELECT a.column1, b.column2
 FROM source.apple.hist a, source.mango.present b
 WHERE (select column3, column4 from source.my.ORANGE where a.id = b.id

{"result":[{
"query": "SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM abcd.hist a, efgh.present b
WHERE (select column3, column4 from UPS where a.id = b.id )"
},
{"query": "SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM apple.hist a, mango.present b
WHERE (select column3, column4 from my.ORANGE where a.id = b.id )"}
]}
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a dictionary {}, with the first key 'result' containing a list [] of dictionaries {} where each dictionary has a key 'query' that goes to a value that looks like a SQL query.

Assuming your output object is called op you can get your desired result as follows:

```
for k in op['result']: # For each dictionary in result
    print(str(k)[1:-1]) # Cast to a string and strip curlies
```

EDIT:

```
def addSource(q):
    lines = q.split("\n")
    for n,k in enumerate(lines):
        if(k.startswith("FROM")):
            q[n] = k.replace("FROM ","FROM source.").replace(", ",", source.")
    return("\n".join(q))
```

and with that,

```
for n,k in enumerate(op['result']):
    op['result'][n]["query"] =  addSource(k["query"])
```

Comment: I need to add the "source." word before the table schemas and then update the dictionary with the updated value.

Comment: Does the code added under the edit make sense? / work?

Comment: I am getting this error  "   for n,k in op['result']:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: my mistake, that has to be for n,k in enumerate(op['result'])

Comment: thanks but now getting this error " return("\n".join(1))
TypeError: can only join an iterable"

Comment: yeah my bad, should have been return(q), I edited it.

Comment: import json
with open('/Users/op.json', 'r') as f:
    op = json.load(f)

def addSource(q):
    lines = q.split("\n")
    for n,k in enumerate(lines):
        if(k.startswith("FROM")):
            q[n] = k.replace("FROM ","FROM source.").replace(", ",", source.")
    return ("\n".join(q))

for n,k in enumerate(op['result']):
    a = op['result'][n]["query"] = addSource(k["query"])
    print(a)

Comment: but I don't see the correct print output. Can you please tell me what I need to change? Thanks a lot.